# How to implement canaries to prevent buffer overflows?

Tags: buffer-overflow

This is probably a very basic question. I've read about canaries, and how they work in theory. You have a global variable that you set to a random number in the prolog of a function, do your function, and then verify its authenticity in the epilog.

```
void foobar(int a, int b)
{
   prolog();
   int c = a;
   int d = b;
   char *buffer[40];
   strcpy(stupidcopy);
   epilog();
}
```

What I don't understand is, how do I place something on the stack in prolog? Like, if I call prolog, and tell it to save a local variable, it'll be on stack, but when we get out of prolog(), won't it be popped? How can I *save* the canary on stack? Do I need to modify esp using assembly code to do this?

Comment: Step 1: Become a compiler

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Usually it's the compiler who generates canaries. *Prologue* and *epilogue* aren't function calls, they're the instructions the compiler places at the beginning and end of a function.

Consider a naive compiler which puts variables on the stack in the same order they appear in the code and doesn't use registers. Then your function might become:

```
// variables on stack
int c;
int d;
char *buffer[40];
int canary;

// prologue
canary = secret;

// normal code
c=a;
d=b;
strcpy(stupidcopy);

// epilogue
if(canary != secret)
    OhNoesABufferOverflow();
return;
```

You can't write this code yourself since compilers can and do optimize storage on the stack. They can reorder variables, keep them in registers and it could even optimize out `canary` entirely since no well-behaved code will ever trigger the condition.

Answer (score 0):

> If you intend to implement it as a **security measurement** than I
> suggest not to, why?

1. First, as @CodesInChaos mentioned in most cases this code will be optimized out.
2. Perfomance penalty - not all functions should use this protection, it involves more actions and affects performance, when you use in MSVC [`/GS`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/gs-buffer-security-check?view=msvc-170) or in GCC `-fstack-protector` flag, the compiler will add canaries / security cookie only in functions that are prune to buffer overflow, not all functions.
3. Safety - in order to truly protect from exploitation of a buffer overflow that corrupts the stack you need to use changing values for canaries, that is another mechanism you will need to implement, but already implemented by the compiler.

> If you just want to implement the mechanism or for debug purposes ,
> you can add a `volatile` buffer with known content at the beginning of
> a function and check it hasn't change at the end of the function.